# Do we get an actual ending in the end of the 11th season of the X Files?

Tags: the-x-files

I have seen certain episodes of the X-Files revival and it feels like the plot has lost its meaning and basically goes nowhere. I feel disappointed since this is one of my all-time favorite shows and my interest in watching the last episodes does not exist anymore. To anyone who saw the whole thing, does the end makes sense?

Comment: If X-Files actually ever reached its end, it would be disappointing, and ruin any chance for future sequels

Comment: @BlueMoon93 It's one thing to leave some loose ends, it's another to leave it on massive cliffhanger. I haven't seen season 11 so I don't know how it ends, but season 10 ended on a huge cliffhanger. They were planning a season 12, but Gillian Anderson made some kind of statement saying she wanted out and so the EPs have said with out her there will be no more future X-Files seasons...https://ew.com/tv/2018/01/10/gillian-anderson-leaving-x-files-american-gods/

Comment: Interesting about them stopping the show without Gillian.  I was so sure that they introduced Einstein and Whats-his-face in S10 specifically so they'd have a new set of agents to take over if/when Scully and Mulder bowed out.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, there's never an 'end' to a show, because of course any can be revived under a pretense.  Blow up the entire universe and, if necessary, there can be a plot-point to revive it.

In the case of X-Files, in the ending sequence,

> The son is shot, but appears to have survived, surfacing at the end.

So it deliberately allows for a storyline to continue.  In this case,

> Mulder, Scully, and the son are certainly left alive.  Visually, I would argue that ex-Navy Seal character, Skinner survived by sliding under the vehicle.  That is pure speculation.

In terms of the actors returning, [they have stated that they will not](https://nerdist.com/gillian-anderson-david-duchovny-x-files-farewell-tca18/), but this is neither the first time they have said this, nor has it prohibited the television show from returning without them, as seen in Seasons 8 & 9; further, they returned for a second movie and for Seasons 10 & 11.